Discovery of a Formula for Geostationary Orbit Distance: Seeking Expert Feedback
I’m an amateur enthusiast without a formal academic background in mathematics or science. Recently, I stumbled upon an idea and derived a formula that I believe calculates the distance traveled along the geostationary orbit (GEO) as a function of the pointing angle (($\gamma$)) from a point on Earth’s surface. The formula seems to account for the fact that the observation point is not at the center of the Earth but on its surface.
Here’s the formula I came up with in Latex:
$$
d = 2R \arcsin \left( \frac{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 + \left[ r \sin \left( \gamma + \frac{3\pi}{2} \right) + R \right]^2 - 2(R-r) \left[ r \sin \left( \gamma + \frac{3\pi}{2} \right) + R \right] \cos(\gamma)}}{2R} \right)
$$
Where:
•    R  is the distance of the GEO from the center of the Earth,
•    r  is the radius of the Earth,
•    gamma is the pointing angle relative to the vertical direction.


I’ve tested the formula for various values of $\gamma$, and it seems to work well for the edge cases ($\gamma = 0 \text{ and } \gamma = \pi$), and it also shows an exponential-like behavior for angles close to $\pi/2$, which makes sense geometrically as the distance to the orbit increases.
I’m curious to know what more experienced mathematicians and physicists think about this. Is this formula known in the literature? Does it correctly account for the geometrical complexities involved?
Any feedback, corrections, or references to similar known formulas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your insights!

can you tell us how you derived the formula? from the finished product alone, it is difficult to tell if the derivation is correct.

This may be interesting but physics is largely about the process rather than the answer so unless you carefully explain how you obtained your expression it is basically a jumble.

You would have to find an expert in the particular field, so that they can properly judge if your approximation is better than what they have, or not.
